# What is wrong with this page onload code?

Tags: javascript

Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCtQQ/10/). Note that the click event works just fine (try clicking anywhere in the output), but not the document load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ach, I finally got it — attaching the event to `window` instead of `document` seems to work much better.

Answer (score 2):

The document requires `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
_bl_event(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', d1, false);
_bl_event(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', d2, false);
```

...though it isn't supported in all browsers.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bCtQQ/15/

This has different meaning from placing a `load` handler on `window`.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is not supported in IE8 and older browsers. [—mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events) *(Edit: I see you updated to reflect this, thanks.)*